# Background issue in android

Tags: android

I used scroll view to scroll whole of my activity but using that my background image got stretched and also if i gave weight sum property to my linearlayout it distrubed the whole layout.Scrolview is working fine but the height of background image got stretched.  I want my background image of same of the block which is showing the content of story.

Pictures of activity :

[image]

[image]

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/empty"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".story_activity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Story Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"-->/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="@drawable/story_des"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/lion" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/story_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:text="This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters.This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters.This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters."
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/story_rate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Rate This Story"
                        android:textColor="#1e5aaa"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rate"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/story_rate"
                        android:src="@drawable/star" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rate1"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate"
                        android:src="@drawable/star" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rate2"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate1"
                        android:src="@drawable/star" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rate3"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate2"
                        android:src="@drawable/star" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/line" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/author_image"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/as" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/author_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_image"
                        android:fontFamily="century-gothic"
                        android:text="Author Title"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pub_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/author_title"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_image"
                        android:fontFamily="century-gothic"
                        android:text="Pve sentences, cjajsxa "
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanku I got the problem, only changed the scroll view  height attribute from  
android:layout_height="wrap_content">  to  
 android:layout_height="matched_parent"> and its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When i want to add a background image to a ScrollView i do this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="... YOUR_DRAWABLE ..."/>

    <ScrollView>
        ... YOUR_CODE ...
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the scroll view height attribute from android:layout_height="wrap_content"> to android:layout_height="matched_parent"> and its will work fine.